# tkinter's image is inserted with extra sides

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wanted to create a graphical interface for my project, but when I tried to insert the project logo into tkinter, the logo was displayed with extra borders, which are not in the image itself.

```
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

height: int = 500
width: int = 700
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("quick_trade")
root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
root.configure(background='#333')


def open_img(path, size=(250, 200)):
    x = path
    image = Image.open(x)
    image = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    return image


img = open_img('dark.PNG')
label = tk.Label(root, image=img)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `bd = 0` like

```
label = tk.Label(root, image=img,bd=0)
```

Alternatively, for your case, say:

```
label = tk.Label(root, image=img,bg='#333')
```

Hope this cleared the effect, as it did for me, do let me know.

Cheers